# Can a read() by one process see a partial write() by another?

Tags: windows, unix, concurrency, operating-system, filesystems

If one process does a write() of size (and alignment) S (e.g. 8KB), then is it possible for another process to do a read (also of size and alignment S and the same file) that sees a mix of old and new data?

The writing process adds a checksum to each data block, and I'd like to know whether I can use a reading process to verify the checksums in the background. If the reader can see a partial write, then it will falsely indicate corruption.

What standards or documents apply here? Is there a portable way to avoid problems here, preferably without introducing lots of locking?

Comment: This is a classic multiuser database problem, and products like oracle maintain concurrency with a lot of locking and other operations.  The simple answer is no.  There is no guarantee.  You have to implement mutexes or file locking or whatever you deem reasonable to make the guarantee.  Some kind of common object that has kernel persistence will solve the problems - mutex, sempahore, lock file, etc.

Comment: Clarification: My question is not about whether the write actually goes to disk, just about whether the other process can see partial writes while the system is fully online. So, it's OK if there is a torn page after a crash, I just don't want to falsely conclude that there is corruption when the other process is in the middle of a write() call.

Comment: write and read usually hit the file cache, in both windows and unix. whamma explains it more clearly below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a function is guaranteed to complete without there being any chance of any other process/thread/anything seeing things in a half finished state, it's said to be ***atomic***. It either has or hasn't happened, there is no part way. While I can't speak to Windows, there are very few file operations in POSIX (which is what Linux/BSD/etc attempt to stick to) that are guaranteed to be atomic. Reading and writing are **not guaranteed to be atomic**.

While it would be pretty unlikely for you to write 2 bytes to a file and another process only see one of those bytes written, if by dumb luck your write straddled two different pages in memory and the VM system had to do something to prepare the second page, it's possible you'd see one byte without the other in a second process. Usually if things are page aligned in your file, they will be in memory, but again you can't rely on that.

[Here's a list](http://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html) someone made of what is atomic in POSIX, which is pretty short, and I can't vouch for it's authenticity. (I can't think of why unlink isn't listed, for example).

I'd also caution you against testing what appears to work and running with it, the moment you start accessing files over a network file system (NFS on Unix, or SMB mounts in Windows) a lot of things that seemed to be atomic before no longer are.

If you want to have a second process calculating checksums while a first process is writing the file, you may want to open a pipe between the two and have the first process write a copy of everything down the pipe to the checksumming process. That may be faster than dealing with locking.

Comment: I believe you answered the question, but "atomic" operations like "mv" usually mean "atomic even in the event of a power failure". I don't need that strong of a guarantee, I just need to know that it appears to be atomic while the system is online.

Comment: Also, the checksumming process is there to guarantee that checksum is still valid after it hits disk (perhaps much later). At the time of the original write, I know the checksum is valid because I just set it, so testing it then won't do any good.

Comment: @Jeff There are subtle differences between "atomic filesystem operations" and "atomic filesystems". If you have a filesystem mounted with the "async" flag, and you do something atomic between two processes it's guaranteed to stay atomic. But it's not guaranteed to be atomic on disk - the async flag means it can write in whatever order it wants even if that leaves things in an inconsistent state. So you can be fully atomic while running and not be atomic on the disk, or even vice versa depending on a lot of things that you can't rely on.

Comment: @Jeff Just because you're reading the file back from a different process doesn't mean you're actually verifying what went to disk. If you write to the disk in one process, then read it back in the other, you're just reading from the kernel's cache, which isn't proving that things got written correctly. Short of unmounting and remounting the entire filesystem, there are no portable ways of telling the OS to __really__ read back from the disk to make sure it got written correctly. Unless you're working in an embedded system with exotic storage, it's safe to assume the write worked.

Comment: I know it may not have hit disk, but it would be good to verify checksums while, e.g., taking a backup, because even if it's not from disk it still passes the checksum and it's still the block I'm backing up. But if it has hit disk, and got corrupted, then I'd like to know before I say the backup was successful.

Comment: To be a little more precise, atomicity and isolation are different. POSIX does not guarantee isolation, meaning an unsynchronized read may see portions of a write in no guaranteed order. Failure-atomicity is typically not guaranteed either: you can issue a cached write, parts of which may get trickled out to the disk which has it's own cache and after a part of this is flushed to the disk, you lose power.